# What is this the sway bar link? 2012 Ford Fusion

Tags: ford, part-identification, fusion, swaybar

Doing some google searches for this, I think this is the sway bar link for a 2012 Ford Fusion.  I noticed it doing an oil change on my car.  Can anyone confirm?  If it is, is it best practice to replace both sides?  Is it easy for someone who isn't a mechanic to fix?  I can do basic car maintenance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your sway bar link. It is best practice to replace both at the same time. Pretty easy to replace so yes, it is a DIY job.